Off-topic Qs: Service reviews that are obviously scams
I'm posting in regards to this question
By the strictest reading of the site rules, asking for a review of a website/service is off-limits. 
However, in the example above, I think it is quite obvious that the site posted is a scam (see my answer on the same question for my reasoning). You can disagree with me on this, but I think there still are a couple of points worth discussing here, which are relevant to the meta of the site:

Specific site reviews should be seen as off-topic, but a general review of a category of site/service seems reasonably on topic. For example "Is MtGox.com a good exchange?" is not within the scope of bitcoin.SE, but "Is a centralized exchange a good place to store coins?" is. 
I don't really feel good about closing a question just to uphold site rules in the strictest sense, if it means that the user may get scammed. Obviously there is a very large, subjective grey-area of 'what qualifies as a scam', so I don't think my opinion really ultimately matters much here, I just mention this because I feel that perhaps there is a way to better handle these sorts of questions, that keeps answers as objective as possible, while also helping mitigate against potential damage/attacks/scams/whatever.

Would a canonical question be a good way to handle this? For example a quick search found this question, but as you can see it remains unanswered, and the comments on it echo my (obvious) worry about subjectivity. 
Nonetheless, I can't help but feel that there is some sort of Q/A that we can point (new) users to, in an effort to help keep them safe. Please excuse me if one already exists, my quick search didn't seem to find anything extremely similar/relevant.
